# load testing gevent sockets

Tags: python, gevent

How can you load test gevent sockets?
I've written a simple server and I want to load test this before I tweak the code to find out what improvements can be done.

Are there any specifics to load testing a socket server?
How would I go about load testing this code so I can compare the results after applying tweaks?

```
from gevent import server
from gevent.monkey import patch_all; patch_all()
import gevent


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, socket, address, server_handler):
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        self.server_handler = server_handler
        gevent.spawn(self.listen)

    def listen(self):
        f = self.socket.makefile()
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                print 'client died'
                break
            line = line.rstrip()
            for addr, c in self.server_handler.users.iteritems():
                msg = '<%s> says: %s' % (self.address, line)
                c.send(msg)

            print '<%s>: %s' % (self.address, line)

    def send(self, msg):
        f = self.socket.makefile()
        f.write('%s\r\n' % msg)
        f.flush()


class ServerHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {}

    def __call__(self, socket, address):
        client = Client(socket, address, self)
        self.users[address] = client
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        print 'connection made'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = server.StreamServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), ServerHandler())
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Why not make a job that: connects to server, does stuff, repeat N times, times time consumed?

Comment: Would that not just result in one connection at a time?
Ideally I would like to know how many concurrent connections it can handle

Comment: True, but it tells you what the latency is and how many requests per second you can handle. For more advanced loadtesting you could use [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)